# selection sort algorithm for 2d char array

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, selection

I am trying to make a selection sort algorithm for a 2d array in C (as the title says), the code compiles but unfortunately it does not sort anything.

is there anything I can change that will make it work? or do I have to start over all together?

```
void sortStrings(char strings[5][32])
{
    int i, j, min;
    for (i = 0; i < sizeof(strings); i++){
        min = i;
        for (j = 0; j < sizeof(strings-1); j++){
            if (strings[i] < strings[min]){
                min = 1;
            }
        }
        if (min != i){
            swapStrings(strings[i], strings[min]);
        }
    }
}
```

Also here is my swapStrings function for reference:

```
void swapStrings(char string1[], char string2[])
{
    char *temp = string1;
    string1 = string2;
    string2 = temp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`sizeof`returns the size taken in memory by the parameter.
In your case, the size of a char isn't the size of your array.
You can get the size of a string using the strlen function.
However, your can't get the size of your array `strings`you need to add a parameter to your function.

Comment: If both `string1` and `string2` are valid *nul-terminated* strings, you can get the length in `swapStrings` without passing the max length of the two as a paramter using `strlen` (or a pointer and a loop). However, I do agree it is probably better to explicitly pass a max length as a parameter to the function.

Answer (score 0):

I see some bugs in your code:

```
for (i = 0; i < sizeof(strings); i++){
```

Why are you using sizeof? sizeof is not for that.

What are you trying to do here:

```
if (strings[i] < strings[min]){
```

It seems to be a bug.

What are you triying to do here?:

```
swapStrings(strings[i], strings[min])
```

Your function `swapStrings` is wrong, because do not return anything and don't change anything.

And finally, can you explain more what are you trying to do?

Comment: `swapStrings` need not return anything to accomplish a swap of strings.

Answer (score 0):

It looks wrong because, during dry run I found that it sent `result` to the `swap` function at the first run.

It's looks like you set `i=Min=j=0` and then checked only if they `!=`;

Plus what Other wrote.

Answer (score 0):

```
void swapStrings(char string1[], char string2[])
{
    char *temp = string1;  //it means nothing in string
    string1 = string2;     //you must use strcpy(string1,string2)
    string2 = temp;
}
```

Comment: Well, you accurately copied the `swapStrings` function to your answer and did add a correct comment, but you may want to expand on your answer to make it more useful to others. Remember, when you answer questions, you step into the role of 'teacher'.

Answer (score 0):

Without passing on the validity of your sort logic, you are missing some *fundamental basics* in string handling in C. Your swap function is:

```
void swapStrings(char string1[], char string2[])
{
    char *temp = string1;
    string1 = string2;
    string2 = temp;
}
```

That logic DOES NOT APPPLY TO STINGS. It is a *character-swap* logic. Why?

- **You cannot assign strings in C**

You must copy strings using either *array indexes* or *pointers* and a loop OR using one of the string library copy functions (e.g. `strcpy`, `strncpy`, `sprintf`, `snprintf`, `memcpy`, etc.). (note: the `printf` family is in `stdio.h`)

Next, to make use of `temp` in `swapStrings` you must know the MAXIMUM length of `string1` and `string2`. Why? you must provide sufficient storage for `temp` to hold the longest of either `string1` and `string2`. How? Either compute the maximum length within `swapStrings` or pass the max length as a parameter to `swapStrings`.

Next, while correct, when you pass arrays to `swapStrings` as `char string1[]`, you mask the conversion of the character array to a **pointer** which takes place each time an array is passed as a parameter to a function. Therefore, the parameter you pass for `string1` need only be `char *string1`. (the conversion is limited to the *first level of indirection*, e.g. if you have a 2D array, say `char strarray[20][64]` it would be converted to a pointer to array `char *strarray[64]` -- the type being `char (*)[64]`)

Passing the max length for `string1` and `string2`, you could use the following to swap the strings:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
...    
void swapStrings (char *string1, char *string2, size_t maxlen12)
{
    char *temp = malloc (maxlen12 + 1); /* you must allocate space for temp */
                                        /* including space for nul-byte     */

    if (!temp) {    /* validate ALL memory allocations */
        fpritnf (stderr, "error: virtual memory exhausted.\n");
        return;
    }

    /* you CANNOT ASSIGN strings, you must copy them */
    strncpy (temp, string1, maxlen12 + 1);
    strncpy (string1, string2, maxlen12 + 1);
    strncpy (string2, temp, maxlen12 + 1);

    free (temp);  /* if you allocate it, you are responsible for freeing it */
}
```

This requires both `string1` and `string2` to be valid *nul-terminated* strings.

**Note:** you can also use a VLA (*Variable Length Array*) instead of allocating with `malloc`, but that is only relevant to C99+ or C89 compilers with explicit VLA extensions added.

**Also Note:** you can assign and swap pointers if you pass the **address of** the pointer as a parameter, but this is for another day.

**Also final Note:** if `string1` and `string2` differ by a large amount (10,000's or 100,000's of chars), you will want to use a different copy function as `strncpy` will write `0`'s to all characters beginning with the *nul-byte* in each string. That can be somewhat inefficient in very long strings that differ in length.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void printArray(char *array[], int size) 
{
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<size; i++)
    {
        printf("%s ", array[i]);        
    }
    printf("\n");
}

/* Selection Sort in Descending Order */
void sortSelectionFromSmallest(char *array[], int size) 
{
    int unsortedStart; /* the start index of unsorted part */
    int i,j;
    int largestIndex;
    char *temp;

    for (unsortedStart = 0; unsortedStart < size - 1; unsortedStart++) 
    {
        /* search for the largest number in unsorted part */
        largestIndex = unsortedStart;
        for (i=unsortedStart + 1; i <= size-1; i++) 
        {
            //if (strcmp(array[largestIndex], array[i]) < 0)
            if (strlen(array[largestIndex]) < strlen(array[i]))
            {
                largestIndex = i;
            }
        }

        /* swap with start of unsorted */       
        temp = array[unsortedStart];
        array[unsortedStart] = array[largestIndex];
        array[largestIndex] = temp;

        /* print the array at intermediate steps */
        printArray(array, size);
    }
}

int main() 
{
    char* array[8] = {"London", "Edo", "Paris", "Taipei", "Beijing", "Singapore", "Berlin", "Shanghai"};
    printf("Original array\n");
    printArray(array, 8);

    printf("\nSorting array\n");    
    sortSelectionFromSmallest(array, 8);

    printf("\nSorted array\n");
    printArray(array, 8);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: the first letter of all words must be uppercase or lowercase. cannot existing both.